# Custom Post Type with WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I am having an issue with categories, my "product" category works, but my "post"categories aren't showing for my products.

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts() {
$labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'product', 'mh-magazine-lite' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'product', 'mh-magazine-lite' ),
    );

   $args = array(
    "label" => __( 'product', 'mh-magazine-lite' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => false,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
            "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "product", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,

    "supports" => false,        
    "taxonomies" => array( "category", "post_tag", "product_cat",            "product_tag", "product_shipping_class", "pa_shirt-sizes" ),
        );
register_post_type( "product", $args );

 // End of cptui_register_my_cpts()
 }
```

Dunno if this is even possible, would like any solutions

Comment: Are you trying to associate your standard "post" categories with your post type of "products"? I'm a little confused as to why you're registering a custom post type of "product" when WooCommerce already does that, but I think I may be misunderstanding the question a little.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want to do, any suggestion how to get this done?